# Does existing constructor remain unaffected if you modify the prototype object for a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

If you modify the prototype object for a constructor function, the changes are only visible to new objects that you create by using that constructor function; existing objects created by using the constructor function will be unaffected. True or False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to test:

```
//
//our constructor
function myThing(){

}

//create a prototype method
myThing.prototype.foo = function(){
  return 'bar'; 
};
//create a prototype property
myThing.prototype.thing = 'hello';

var bar = new myThing();

console.log(bar.foo());//bar
console.log(bar.thing);//hello




//modify prototype
myThing.prototype.foo = function(){
  return 'baz'; 
};

myThing.prototype.thing = 'goodbye';

//create new
var bar2 = new myThing();



//log old
console.log(bar.foo()); //baz
console.log(bar.thing); //goodbye

//log new
console.log(bar2.foo()); //baz 
console.log(bar2.thing); //goodbye
//
```

So as you can see your statement is **false** in this case: if your objects are using the prototype methods and properties and those methods or properties are modified (while maintaining the same prototype reference, see Oriol's answer for the difference), the existing objects will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

True. The magic is done through the internal [[Prototype]] property, which determines from which other object the object inherits from.

When you instantiate a constructor, the [[Prototype]] of the instances is set to the current `prototype`.

Changing that `prototype` later won't affect previous instances, their [[Prototype]] will still point to the previous `prototype`.

The change will only affect instances created after the change, which will have their [[Prototype]] set to the new `prototype`.

```
function F(){}
var f1 = new F();
f1 instanceof F; // true
F.prototype = {foo: 'bar'}
var f2 = new F();
f1.foo; // undefined
f2.foo; // "bar
f1 instanceof F; // false
f2 instanceof F; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. That existing instances will be unaffected is

- **true** when you set the `.prototype` property of the constructor function to a different prototype object.
- **false** when you modify the prototype object by setting properties on it.